# What are the methods of experimentally measuring the observables in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, measurements, observables

Perhaps due to the limited number of textbooks on quantum mechanics I have consulted, I have seen presented the fundamental principles related to observables, but have never seen a somewhat systematic discussion of how specific measurement of each of those observables can be carried out in practice or in thought experiments.

For instance, the position, energy, or momentum (separately, of course) of a particle in a potential well (approximately infinitely high, in particular), or of a quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator. How do we measure these (perhaps just in thought experiments)?

---

[text deleted after the first answer: the energy or angular momentum of the electron of a hydrogen atom]

Comment: a typical example is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, spin can effectively be measured that way. But I am not sure whether the Stern–Gerlach experiment can be adapted to measure the energy or whatever quantity of a particle in a potential well.

Comment: There are problems with that experiment even for measuring the spin of the electron of a hydrogen atom. If you let electrons go through the magnetic field, you have driven them out of the atom already and are no longer measuring the electron IN the atom. If you let the hydrogen atoms go instead, you first have to determine the spin of the nucleus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, what is in a potential well doesn't touch our apparatuses. What we do is another trick. We *entangle* the particle in the potential well with another particle that gets out from the well and reaches our apparatuses. For instance scattering experiments can give us information about internal structures.

The procedure goes as follows: let an internal particle be in a superposition of states

$\psi = \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}} (|A \rangle + |B\rangle )$,

where $|A\rangle $ and $|B\rangle $ are two internal states. Then we bring another particle $|p\rangle $ that interacting with the state $|A\rangle $ passes to a state of linear momentum $|\vec a\rangle $, and interacting with the state $|B\rangle $ passes to a state with linear momentum $|\vec b\rangle $,

$|p\rangle |\psi\rangle  \to \frac {1}{\sqrt{2}} (|A\rangle |\vec a\rangle  + |B\rangle |\vec b\rangle )$.

Thus, we can get information of internal states. Structures of molecules and many microscopic data are obtained this way. Of course, the actual experiments are more complicated, in this answer I only described the general idea.

Comment: Please be kind and use \rangle. Someone poor soul will end up editing your answer anyway, so why not save him/her the trouble?

Comment: Thank you for making the idea clear to me! Oh, if I am not mistaken, I think there is a typo in the second formula, where the ϕ should be ψ.

Comment: @lionelbrits : I can't understand why do you like the \rangle. It's one more complication. I dislike so much the editing.

Comment: But how do we measure the other particle's linear momentum successfully? I mean, in scattering experiments it is easy to measure the directions of outgoing probe particles, but what methods are used to determine the magnitudes of their linear momenta? Also, how do we measure the energy of an outgoing particle? Though I know a couple of such methods,  I think I know too little about it.

Comment: @Metrica : linear momentum is not a problem to measure. Far from the target, you just measure under which angle was deflected the scattered particle, with respect to the flux incident to the target. For measuring the energy, some methods pass the scattered particles through materials and according to the energy of the particle, electrons are smashed from atoms, s.t. an electric pulse can be obtained and calibrated to the particle's energy.

Comment: Because everybody in professional physics uses rangle as opposed to "greater than". For some people, reading can be challenging and good typesetting goes a long way to getting your message understood.